# What is the most effective method to rewrite www.example.com/?city_name="New-York" to /cities/newyork

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have urls that are in this format

```
www.example.com/?city_name="New-York"
```

And I was wondering if there was a way to automatically rewrite this url to

```
www.example.com/cities/new-york
```

Using rewrite rules.

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I don't know in what direction to go, and I'm not too familiar with apache or mod-rewrite, but I have looked at my .htaccess file and tried to look at the different regex patterns available.

Comment: Something along the lines of `RewriteRule ^cities/(.*)$ ?city_name=$1`

Comment: The mod_rewrite documentation is [over here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/) and has lots of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `RewriteCond` on the query string, then a `RewriteRule` using the result.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^city_name="([\w]+)" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /cities/%1? [L,R]
```

The `RewriteCond` runs a regex on the query string, looking for your `city_name` parameter. `NC` is the no case flag, to make the regex case-insensitive. In the actual `RewriteRule` directive, we completely rewrite the path to `/cities/%1`, where `%1` is the first matched group from the last successful `RewriteCond` directive, in this case, the slug for the city requested. We put a `?` at the end to wipe the query string from the request, then pass the `L` and `R` flags to issue a full 302 redirect.